# Php: object comparaison (one of them sent through webservice)

Tags: php, web-services, object, soap, comparison

I'm trying to compare two objects like this:

```
    if($obj1==$obj2){
    ...
```

But my comparison always return false!

$obj1 is a param of my function (called through a Webservice) of type "MySoapObject".

$obj2 is an object of type "MySoapObject" loaded from my database.

In my test print_r of my both objects give me this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [establishment] => stdClass Object
        (
            [f_establishment_id] => 4
            [f_name] => MyEstablishment
            [f_display_name] => v
            [f_main_web_link] => 
            [f_contact] => 
            [f_country_code] => 
            [f_city] => 
            [f_zip_code] => 
            [f_postal_address] => 
            [f_default_language] => 
            [f_timezone] => 
            [f_cloud_synchronisation_action] => TO_SYNC
        )

    [site_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [f_site_id] => Site1
                    [f_status] => TO_DISABLE
                    [f_name] => Site1
                )

        )

)
```

By the way, if I try this:

```
    if(print_r($obj1)==print_r($obj2)){
    ...
```

The result is true!

Have you an idea of where could be the problem? How to solve it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531967/comparing-2-objects-php

Comment: FYI, the reason `print_r($obj1)==print_r($obj2)` is `TRUE` is because `print_r()` returns `TRUE` unless you pass the flag that tells it to return a string.  So you're essentially comparing `TRUE==TRUE`, which, obviously, is `TRUE`.

Comment: Did you read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php ? Check, are both your objects really instances of the same class or not. BTW: I'm pretty sure that using object comparison for case with nested objects is not a good idea because of recursion.

Comment: BTW: if you think about comparison like strings - you have to think about sorting all your keys right before converting object to a string. You can do convert object to string, as example, by **json_encode**.

Comment: Indeed, print_r($obj1)==print_r($obj2) will always be true. Nevertheless I can see that the two string returned are exactly the same.
Of course I can create a function to check property by property, but I would have prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

for object comparison you can use :

```
 if($obj1===$obj2){
 }
```

check the documentation
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: == for value and === for object comparison

Comment: I think he is trying to compare the values of the objects and not the types. Where is it stated that === is for object comparison?

Comment: === definitely will not help ) Take a look at manual, please: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

Comment: Indeed === is not a solution here.